# SQL aggregate function when count(*)=1 so there can be only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, group

Sometimes you write a grouped query where each group is a single row, as `having count(*) = 1`.  This means that the usual aggregate functions like `min`, `max`, `sum` and so on are a bit pointless: the min equals the max, equals the sum, equals the average.  Since there's exactly one value to aggregate.

I usually end up picking `min` arbitrarily.  If we take the familiar example of a table mapping a book to its author(s), I might want to query just books that have a single author:

```
-- For books that have a single author, pull back that author's id.
select book_id,
       min(author_id) as author_id
       -- I could equally well use max(author_id) or even sum(author_id)...
from book_authors
group by book_id
having count(*) = 1
```

That works, but it seems it could be expressed better.  I'm not actually interested in the 'minimum' per se, but just to get the single value which I know exists.  Some column types (such as `bit` in Microsoft SQL Server) do not support the `min` aggregate function so you have to do workarounds like `convert(bit, min(convert(int, mycol)))`.

So, I expect the answer will be no, but is there some better way to specify my intent?

```
select book_id,
       there_must_be_one_value_so_just_return_it(author_id) as author_id
from book_author
group by book_id
having count(*) = 1
```

Clearly, if you're not requiring `count(*)=1` then you no longer guarantee a single value and the special aggregate function could not be used.  That error could be caught when the SQL is compiled.

The desired result would be equivalent to the `min` query above.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server (2016) but as this is a fairly "blue sky" kind of question, I would be interested in replies about other SQL dialects too.

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: Some rdbms have a special `any_value` aggregate function which seems to do what you want (if I understand correctly). SQL Server does not support it unfortunately.

Comment: Interally, SQL does indeed have an "any" aggregate and will use it in situations like this.  You don't need to worry about this level of detail in trying to rewrite your queries for you - we've already done that kind of optimization for the normal cases.  Your assertion is not correct, it's just that we don't force this on the user to do something "hacky" to get faster performance.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT is there a way you recommend to get the internal "any" optimization when reading columns of type `bit`?

Comment: I would need to see a specific example for bit + group by.  there are various optimizations done in, for example, columnstore + batch mode for certain aggregates already.  Perhaps we didn't make any work on bit in row mode - I'd need to check the code

Comment: I was thinking of the workaround `convert(bit, min(convert(int, mycol)))` that one must use instead of `min(mycol)` when `mycol` is of type bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, instead, use a windowed `COUNT` and then filter based on that:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ba.book_id,
           ba.author_id,
           COUNT(ba.book_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ba.book_id) AS Authors
    FROM dbo.book_authors ba)
SELECT c.book_id,
       c.author_id
FROM CTE c
WHERE c.Authors = 1;
```

An alternative method would be to use a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT ba.book_id,
       ba.author_id
FROM dbo.book_authors ba
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.book_authors e
              WHERE e.book_id = ba.book_id
              GROUP BY e.book_id
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 1);
```

I have not tested performance on either with a decent amount of data, however, I would *hope* that for a correlated subquery with a well indexed table, you should see better performance.

Comment: @EdAvis While this looks simpler, it is likely to perform worse. Usable if you want to just simplify, but don't use it in performance critical situations

Comment: `COUNT(ba.book_id)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` if `book_id` is not nullable

Comment: Good point, @Charlieface , I should have caveated the performance. Was just writing a version of a correlated subquery, so I'll add that in the notes.

Comment: Hmmm, correlated subquery probably even worse, although you haven't posted it yet

Comment: Thanks.  On my admittedly small data set, I found the windowed count to be much slower than either the grouped subquery (I joined to it rather than `exists`, but should be equivalent) or the `min` technique.  The subquery and `min` were about the same in reads but `min` used a little more CPU.